# Load the mesh file with boundary marks

Tags: mesh-generation, fenics

I'm want to load a mesh from a file, generated by [triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html), and I want to use the boundary marks of its nodes (boundary marks of the file). It is possible?

Also, I can change the mesh generator (or convert its output file), but I want to use the marks of the nodes of the file, is it possible?

Comment: You can write a tiny tool to convert your mesh file to a format which GMSH can read.

Comment: My question is the same, if I have the mesh en gmsh, how can I load the its boundary node marks?

Answer (score 2):

Since GMSH was mentioned in the comments as a possible meshing tool, the common way to deal with it there is to create a `Physical Line`.

The simplest `.geo` (modeling and meshing a square):

```
cl=0.5;
Point(1) = {1.,1.,0.,cl};
Point(2) = {-1.,1.,0.,cl};
Point(3) = {-1.,-1.,0.,cl};
Point(4) = {1.,-1.,0.,cl};

Line(1) = {1,2};
Line(2) = {2,3};
Line(3) = {3,4};
Line(4) = {4,1};

Line Loop (1) = {1,2,3,4};
Surface(1) = {1};
Physical Surface(1) = {1};   // that is "1" the tag for your 2-D elements, by default, triangles
Physical Line(2) = {1,2,3,4}; // that is the tag "2" for your contour lines; thus, boundary nodes
```

After meshing, it will create both 2-D and 1-D mesh elements. Looking inside the generated `*.msh`, you will be able to easily distinguish between them. In that way, it would also be easy to assign different boundary conditions to different lines (simply by creating several `Physical Line`'s).

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to generate a mesh in xml format (to be the input of a fenics code, for example with dolfin-convert) only generates a mesh.xml, but I also need load the marks of the nodes 

For example:

mesh = Mesh("mesh.xml")
bd = MeshFunction("size_t", mesh, "mesh_facet_region.xml")
ds = Measure("ds", subdomain_data=bd)

How can I generate the "mesh_facet_region.xml", or, how can I load the marks of faces and nodes of the file mesh in fenics?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not actually a Fenics user. But take a look here: https://fenicsproject.org/qa/9983/setting-boundary-conditions-for-meshes-generated-by-gmsh/ the second answer implies that `dolphin-convert` ignores Physical Surfaces and Lines if only one region is there.

Comment: Thanks @anton, but my question is related with fenics only. I don't know why that solutions doesn't work for me, and I don't have information in the fenics manual.

Comment: @yemino If I were you, I would write a tiny tool which converts .msh file of GMSH to xml file. I wrote such a tool except my output is a .dat file for Tecplot and/or .vtk file for Paraview. Have a look at my repository: https://github.com/truongd8593/gmsh-to-vtk-and-tecplot

Comment: Thanks @chuyenvien94 for share your Fortran code, but,  Can I load the *.vtk or *.dat mesh data (with boundary conditions fo the nodes) in fenics? Because that is my question: how load the mesh (with the boundary marks) in fenics.

Comment: I hope I can buy some time for studying fenics mesh file format. After that I'm pretty sure that I can find a reasonable solution.